# Mahapps Metro Controls:Tile Background Image

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

I want to create with Mahapps.Metro a cool Windows 8 look.
I used the `<Controls:Tile/>` elements. Here is my wpf Code:

```
        <Controls:Tile Title="Artikel einstellen" TiltFactor="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Height="150">
            <Controls:Tile.Background>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />
            </Controls:Tile.Background>
        </Controls:Tile>
        <Controls:Tile Title="Artikel verkauft" TiltFactor="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Height="150"/>
        <Controls:Tile Title="Artikel bezahlt" TiltFactor="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Height="150"/>
        <Controls:Tile Title="Artikel entfernen" TiltFactor="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Height="150"/>
```

Now I get this result:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

I downloaded the `Icons & Resource Package` of MahApps.Metro & included them in the `app.xaml` file with this code:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

[MahApps.Metro.IconPacks](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks) require less code and has more icons

```
<Controls:Tile Width="300" Height="150" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Title="Hello!">
    <Grid>
        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="FlagCheckeredSolid" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    </Grid>
</Controls:Tile>
```

Don't forget to call the namespace

```
xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
```

Comment: MahApps.Metro.IconPacks takes a lot of space, has a lot of excess, and slows down the loading of the application. If you use 5-10 icons, it is easier to place them in your own xaml dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I have to create a `<Rectangle/>` inside the `<Tile/>` like this:

```
<Controls:Tile Title="Artikel einstellen" TiltFactor="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Height="150">
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Controls:Tile>
```